# Updated Apple Mail, now hung and cannot send or receive emails

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, software-update

A couple of days ago I updated Apple Mail but after the update its hung up. Nothing seems to be working. After I launch it, I am not able to send or receive any emails. I am asked to reset it by some professional but before resetting it I want to backup all my data. I am not relying on Time Machine as well because it starts backing up everything on the Mac. Looking for a decent solution to backup apple mail but how can I do it if it's hung up like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go directly to the folder where Mail saves its data through the Finder and duplicate it to store a copy elsewhere.
Inside the Finder, menu *Go > Go to Folder* and then paste this path:

```
~/Library/Mail/V5
```

It is that V5 folder you'd want to back up before reseting Mail.
There is also some software solutions like [mailbackupx](http://www.mailbackupx.com/) but I never used it so I can't say what it's worth.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Mail Backup X is an amazing application to work with. Its simple and easy to understand unlike all the complicated steps and Time Machine, Mail backup X is really very easy. Thanks once again.